# Jquery - check required field for different parent

Tags: jquery, html

I have form with number of sections.

At the end of each section i have NEXT button for the next section

I also have jquery scrip for fields validation.

I would like to "tell" the script if it should check the all form or just the specific section. for that i need to use some function that get the PARENT name.

how can i "tell" to some function who is the PARENT that contain the fields??

JQUERY:

```
$( '#regForm' ).submit( function( event ) {

    $( '#regForm' ).find( 'select, textarea, input' ).each(function(){


        if ( $(this).parents(".form-group").attr("data-required") == "required")
        {

            if ( ! $( this ).val() )
            {

                $( this ).parents(".form-group").find('.field-msg').html('required field');

                flag = false;

            }   

        }

    });

});
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="regForm">

        <div class="row form_section form_section_block">

            <div class="form-group" data-required="required">
                INPUT FIELD HERE
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" data-required="required">
                FIELD HERE
            </div>          

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn_next">CHECK SECTION VALIDETION AND GO NEXT SECTION</button>

        </div>

        <div class="row form_section form_section_block"  data-secID="10">

            <div class="form-group" data-required="required">
                INPUT FIELD HERE
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn_next">CHECK SECTION VALIDETION AND GO NEXT SECTION</button>

        </div>


        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_submit">CHECK ALL SECTION AND SUBMIT</button>    

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior of form in above code :

```
event.preventDefault()
```

To get parent section you can use:

```
$parent = $(this).parents(".form_section");
```

Comment: So, can i do this -  `$($parent ).find( 'select, textarea, input' ).each(function(){` ?